# Как вычислить следующую точку отрезка

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinter в python при рисовании линии
`canvas.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2)`
рисует от x1,y1 (включительно) до x2,y2 (НЕвключительно).

Хочу рисовать линию line(x1,y1,x2,y2) до x2,y2 (включительно). Дорисовывать еще одну точку (другой линией) не вариант - получается два разных объекта.
По каком алгоритму вычисляется предыдущая точка? Чтобы пересчитать x2,y2, так чтобы линия включала эту точку.

п.с. так не только tkinter рисует, но еще, например, winapi...

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Можно пересчитать конечную точку, так чтобы длина увеличилась на 1 пиксель (грубо говоря, поделить вектор на его длину, потом умножить на длину + 1).

Comment: Кстати, если вам помог мой ответ к предыдущему вашему вопросу, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку слева от него).

Comment: а сделать и x2, и y2 на единицу больше перед отрисовкой - не вариант?

Comment: @Jack_oS это будет работать только если x2 > x1 и y2 > y1, а уже на горизонтальных и вертикальных линиях будет криво работать (буквально, они перестанут быть горизонтальными и вертикальными).

Comment: @insolor точно... ок, инкрементить при x2 > x1 и y2 > y1, наоборот - уменьшать на 1, при 0 - не изменять...

Comment: @Jack_oS, ну это не совсем "честно", плюс при нулевой длине нужно все равно к обеим координатам 1 прибавлять (чтобы просто пиксель нарисовать).

Answer (score 3):

`capstyle=tk.PROJECTING` дорисовывает недостающий пиксел:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg="white")
canvas.pack()

x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 10, 300, 200
canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='red', capstyle=tk.PROJECTING)
canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Дополнение

тесты на Windows показывают, что решение выше не работает. Можно нарисовать отрезок в двух направлениях. На Linux и на Windows работает:

```
# было так:
# canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='red', capstyle=tk.PROJECTING)
# стало так:
canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, x1, y1, fill='red')
```

Спасибо пользователю [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor).

Comment: Проверил на Windows 7 - красного пикселя не видно, черная линия полностью покрывает красную: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMA5Q.png Хотя на Linux работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда `canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, x1, y1, fill='red')`. На windows сработает?

Comment: Интересная идея. Да, так работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSaxs.png

Comment: Рисование в двух направлениях - интересная идея.

Comment: Вот интересно, что делает capstyle=tk.PROJECTING. Что там в исходном коде.

Comment: Быстрый поиск `PROJECTING -> projecting -> square` привёл меня в код на TCL который я не понимаю. Документация требует чтобы в конце линии был нарисован квадрат шириной с линию.

Comment: Если задать толщину линии, то края скругляются.
`canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, x1, y1, fill='red', width = 20)` `canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 20)`
https://ibb.co/TYxc2LB

Comment: The cap style of a line is the shape of the end of the line. Styles are:

tk.BUTT: The end of the line is cut off square at a line that passes through the endpoint.

tk.PROJECTING: The end of the line is cut off square, but the cut line projects past the endpoint a distance equal to half the line's width.

tk.ROUND: The end describes a semicircle centered on the endpoint.

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/cap-join-styles.html

Comment: Да, документация правильная. Но на Windows результат отличается от Linux.

Comment: Под win10 при толщине 1 capstyle=tk.PROJECTING не влияет, толще уже влияет. Но это тоже не то, т.к. на половину ширины длиннее становится.

Answer (score 1):

"Нормального" способа я не нашел, ниже "геометрический" способ (поделить линию на ее длину, потом умножить на длину + 1):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg="white")
canvas.pack()


def regular_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)


def elongated_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    Dx = x2 - x1
    Dy = y2 - y1

    length = (Dx**2 + Dy**2) ** 0.5

    Dx = Dx / length * (length + 1)
    Dy = Dy / length * (length + 1)

    x2 = x1 + Dx
    y2 = y1 + Dy

    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)


x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 10, 300, 200
# Рисуем "удлиненную" красную линию, потом поверх нее неудлиненную
# (в идеале должен остаться виден только один красный пиксель,
# но в итоге красный будет местами просвечиваться по всей длине)
elongated_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="red")
regular_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

root.mainloop()
```

Увеличенный x4 результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще вариант просто через `x2 += sgn(Dx)`, `y2 += sgn(Dy)`:

```
import math


def sign(x):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986718/4752653
    return math.copysign(1, x)


def elongated_line2(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs):
    Dx = x2 - x1
    Dy = y2 - y1

    x2 += sign(Dx)
    y2 += sign(Dy)

    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)
```